# checks if value in a dictionaries list values is unique

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
  'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
  'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'],
  'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}


provs = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 1, 'PCP5': 1}
```

How do I check if an item in these list values is unique and doesnt appear anywhere else in the dictionary?  If it is unique append the 'member' and that 'PCP' to a new dictionary called `matches = dict()` remove that member from `'mems'` and then add any other leftover 'PCP' to their count in `provs`. Oh, and remove the one that is unique in `mems`

result should look like

```
mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'],
'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}

provs = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 2, 'PCP5': 2}

matches = ['member7' : 'PCP4'}
```

I have no idea how to do this.  I tried starting making a counter for the PCPs in `mems` and finding the ones with 1 and then adding to `matches` but it gives the wrong member, 'member9'.

```
pcpCounts = dict(collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_members.values())))
print(pcpCounts)
{'PCP1': 3, 'PCP2': 2, 'PCP4': 1, 'PCP5': 2}

for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(memsCounter.items(), pcpCounter.items()):
if v2 == 1:
    match[k] = k2

print(matches)
{'member9': 'PCP4'}
```

Why does the integrity not maintain when I do this.  More importantly, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
  'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
  'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'],
  'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}

provs = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 1, 'PCP5': 1}
```

First, you can reverse `mems`:

```
d1 = {}
for mem, pcps in mems.items():
    for pcp in pcps:
        d1.setdefault(pcp, []).append(mem)

# {'PCP1': ['member2', 'member6', 'member9'], 'PCP2': ['member2', 'member7'], 'PCP5': ['member6', 'member7', 'member9'], 'PCP4': ['member7']}
```

It's now easy to compute the `matches`: filter the dict on `len(mems)` and reverse it again:

```
matches = {mems[0]: pcp for pcp, mems in d1.items() if len(mems) == 1}
# {'member7': 'PCP4'}
```

You can create a `new_mems` dict that does not contain the matching `pcp`:

```
new_mems = {mem: [pcp for pcp in pcps if pcp not in matches.values()] for mem, pcps in mems.items()}
# {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'], 'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'], 'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP5'], 'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
```

And then use a counter to update `provs`:

```
import collections
new_provs = collections.Counter(provs)
for mem, pcp in matches.items():
    new_provs.update(mems[mem]) # add 1 to each count
    new_provs[pcp] -= 2 # was 0 + 1 (line above) -> is 0

# Counter({'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 2, 'PCP5': 2, 'PCP4': 0})
```

Comment: works! Just need to pop that member that was matched out of new_mems, but also, 'PCP4' still shows in new_provs but with count 0.

Comment: @BenSmith. Not tested, but `del new_provs[pcp]` on the last line should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

To start it might make it easier if you create a set to see if it exists first, and then if it does, find the members it belongs to.

```
mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
  'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
  'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'],
  'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}

provs = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 1, 'PCP5': 1}

members = {}
x = set()
for k,v in mems.items():
    for i in v:
        x.add(i)
        try:
            members[i].append(k)
        except KeyError:
            members[i] = [k,]

print(x)
print(members)

for k in provs:
    if k in x:
        print('KEY: {0} in {1}'.format(k,members[k]))
        print('KEY: {0} in {1}'.format(k,len(members[k]))) # count the references.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the Counter here just turn it into a set filtered by only the single occurring provs then use `set.intersection` as your check.

```
from collections import Counter

mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'], 'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'], 'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'], 'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
provs = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 1, 'PCP5': 1}

#I'm using sum here instead of itertools.chain. It serves the same purpose
prov_counts = {p for p, c in Counter(sum(mems.values(), [])).items() if c == 1} 
prov_filter = map(prov_counts.intersection, mems.values())

matches = {m: list(p) for m, p in zip(mems, prov_filter) if p}

print(matches)
```

---

```
{'member7': ['PCP4']}
```

Comment: Cool!, how could you make the result not be a list, just `{'member7': 'PCP4'}`

Comment: I made it a list in case there was a chance for multiple elements being exclusive to one key. If you only want the one just use `p.pop()` instead of `list(p)`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is changing the second part of your code. Once you have the counts, you can iterate over original values checking which value is unique.

```
>>> mems = {'member2': ['PCP1', 'PCP2'],
... 'member6': ['PCP1', 'PCP5'],
... 'member7': ['PCP2', 'PCP4', 'PCP5'],
... 'member9': ['PCP1', 'PCP5']}
>>> import collections, itertools
>>> pcpCounts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mems.values()))
>>> matches = {}
>>> for k, pcps in mems.items():
...     for v in pcps:
...         if pcpCounts[v] == 1:
...             matches[k] = v
...
>>> matches
{'member7': 'PCP4'}
```

Comment: nice,  then how would I delete the member from ms and the provider from provs whilst counting